Is there anything special about a (Toyota) Hybrid Auxilliary battery?
My 2018 Toyota Prius V battery needs to be replaced.
The current battery is an S46B24R battery which is described as a "Hybrid" battery and and says "Auxiliary AGM" - at least it does on the Century drop-in replacement.   Likewise the replacement has a whole lot of codes which mean very little to me under "Special Features" - AGM, CH, CV, FA, MF, PV.    The battery is only 45AH, with a CCA rating of 325.
This battery only comes with a pathetic 18-24 month guarantee, and is about twice the price of a "regular" battery with similar capacity and higher CCA rating - eg the NS60X MF - which has a 430CCA and 45AH rating, with a 40 month warranty (same brand).   The latter battery is described just as a Sealed Lead Acid Battery.
On the flip side, the car store website I'm looking to buy the battery from says the battery is not compatible with my car.  (Of-course I've known it to be wrong before so I don't put to much stock in what it claims).
It may be worth commenting that the battery is located in the boot of the Prius - so I posit that the CCA rating is not that relevant as the battery is far from the engine, so presumably its not being used to start it (which is consistent with other posts I've read).
Is there anything special about the Hybrid battery or is this just a bit of a money making scheme and a regular Sealed Lead Acid battery will work just as well?  Do I need something with a 45 amp rating (I can get batteries with a 42 amp rating for significantly less)

Which battery are you replacing, the engine start battery or hybrid? The 12v battery is AGM, more expensive than EFB (2nd best) and flooded battery (least expensive)?



Per my post, the 12v  auxiliary battery. (Why)  Do I need to use an AGM battery?

The oem AGM battery and presuming owner's manual recommendation suggests electronics are power hungry when in hybrid or engine power. In hybrid mode, the AGM battery is not recharged until the engine runs with alternator recharging the battery. AGM and EFB batteries are designed for demands of electrical/electronics in vehicles. Wet cell batteries are not designed for deep discharge;  starting draws high current with recharging while driving. Your choice to buy whatever battery you can afford and if upgrading to a higher capacity AGM, be sure it meets dimensional fit in your Prius.

Comment and answer seem to be switched around.
